# HTML 'pre' style disabling mobile formatting in iOS mail

Tags: html, ios, iphone, html-email, whitespace

I'm running into a strange problem with html formatting in iOS. We have an application that sends a daily digest email with a summary of the day's messages. To preserve the whitespace and formatting, the body of each message is displayed with

```
<p style="white-space: pre"> message text here </p>
```

This works perfectly in everything except for the native iOS mail app. For some reason, when the email is viewed in that app, it shrinks the content to fit the screen. If I take out the style tab, the content is sized normally, but all the whitespace gets stripped out and the messages are just uniform blobs of text.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?